# Getting error Liquibase validation failed because checkum has changed in GITHUB Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, liquibase, checksum

I am getting the error Liquibase checksum validation failed.

**Error**

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Validation Failed:
 1 change sets check sum
      changelog.sql::3::snowflake was: 8:f97afb605f986bcfcc0d3e4ecf5208e6 but is now: 8:a10040290479269659939671e8a14db0
```

AnyIdea how to debug this issue in GITHUB Action and Runner.

Answer (score 2):

delete the record for checksum value for that I was getting the error and It is resolved now.